# Trouble with DateTime.ParseExact

Tags: c#, winforms, datetime

I am working on a reminder application. The applications stores the reminder Date, Time and DateLastShown (in different fields) in the database and pulls them out to performs checks.

All dates are in "d/MM/yyyy" format. My problem is that when i pull the dates from the DB and try to store back into DateTime format they are still being shown in "M/d/yyyy" format which is not how the app needs to be.

I essentially need to pull the values from the DB do some checks to determine if it's time to show the reminder and do so. It seems rather straight forward, maybe i am making some small error.

Below is my code with comments. 
Any help really appreciated.

```
public void CheckReminders()
    {
        IQueryable<Reminder> reminders;
        DateTime reminderDate;
        DateTime reminderTime;
        DateTime reminderLastShown;
        DateTime todayDate;
        DateTime timeNow;            

        while (true)
        {
            try
            {
                db = new StudioManagementEntities();
                reminders = from r in db.Reminders
                            select r;

                foreach (Reminder r in reminders)
                {
                    if (r.Enabled == 1)
                    {
                        if (r.Recurring == 1)
                        {                              
                            // This is the code i was using before when the date was   in "M/d/yyyy" format
                            // which seems to be default.
                            reminderTime = DateTime.Parse(r.Time);
                            timeNow = DateTime.Parse(DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString());

                            if (r.DateLastShown != DateTime.Today.ToShortDateString() && timeNow >= reminderTime)
                            {
                                FrmReminder frmReminder = new FrmReminder(r.Id, true);
                                frmReminder.ShowDialog();
                                r.DateLastShown = DateTime.Today.ToShortDateString();                                                                   
                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            // Now i need to pass in "d/M/yyyy" format but the 
                            // code seems to return in "M/d/yyyy" format.    

                            reminderDate = DateTime.ParseExact(r.Date, "d/MM/yyyy", null);  
                            // Even this returns in wrong format
                            reminderDate = DateTime.ParseExact("24/01/2013", "d/MM/yyyy", null);                        
                            // Have tried with CultureInfo.InvariantCulture too.
                            MessageBox.Show(reminderDate.ToString());

                            return;

                            if (
                                r.DateLastShown != DateTime.Today.Date.ToShortDateString() //&&
                                //r.Date == DateTime.ParseExact(DateTime.Today, "d/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).ToString() //&&
                                //now.TimeOfDay.TotalSeconds >= reminderTime.TimeOfDay.TotalSeconds
                               )
                            {
                                FrmReminder frmReminder = new FrmReminder(r.Id, true);
                                frmReminder.ShowDialog();
                                r.DateLastShown = DateTime.Today.ToShortDateString();                                                      
                            }
                        }                            
                    }                        
                }

                db.SaveChanges();
            }              
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
            }

            // Check every minute
            Thread.Sleep(60000);   
        }
    }
```

And the DB table.
[image]

Comment: What's the data type of `Reminder.Time`? What is it's _exact value_ when you retrieve it? (not the value of `reminderTime`, but of `r.Time`)

Comment: Don't have strings for dates in the database or your Reminder object, but use dates instead, and the problem goes away.

Comment: @Jon I had problem with MSSQL and date format in the beginning so resorted to storing as string, i know its not ideal.

Comment: Are you using something outside the range 1753-01-01 to 9999-01-01? Because otherwise MSSQL datetime can indeed work, and it makes more sense to fix your problem with the sensible and efficient solution, than to fix your problem with the kludgy workaround to that problem.

Comment: The only format that makes sense for storing dates as strings is `yyyy-MM-dd`, and even then you don't want to do that in a database that has dedicated data types for date/time.  Otherwise, you are going to have lots of problems like the one you showed here, and indexing/querying is going to be painfully slow and inefficient.

Comment: SQL DateTime (or DateTime2 on newer versions) has no "format". If you use entities and wrapper code like it looks like in your example, you should be perfectly safe. If you need to write queries, I'd suggest ISO-Format as input: '20130413 14:20:00' which MSSQL will recognize in any configuration. It is a huge stability and reliability risk (not to mention performance issue) to store dates non-date types...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the parsing into the date object is not erroring out, you are just having a problem with your output when you call [.ToString().](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k494fzbf%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

From the docs:

> The ToString method returns the string representation of the date and
>   time in the calendar used by the current culture.

If you need something other than the user's current culture settings, you can specify that using a format string in the overloaded [ToString()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zdtaw1bw%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method:

```
   var reminderDate = DateTime.ParseExact("24/01/2013", "d/MM/yyyy", null);

   MessageBox.Show(reminderDate.ToString("d/MM/yyyy"));
```

Also, as others have stated in comments, if possible you should be using the date data type in your database instead of storing the values as strings.

Comment: Thank you very much. In the future i will definitely using DateTime type in DB. Have a great day.